# value >= min && value <= max': is not true. music player

Tags: flutter, dart

Hello I am crating music player sound is fetch from internet  if I try to  play  music less than 5 minutes its working fine but if I try to play song more than or equal to 5 minutes duration. I am getting this issue please expert help me what issue what things  do I need solved  I am beginner  I don't have any idea I would like appreciate your answer

import 'dart:io';

```
import 'package:audioplayers/audio_cache.dart';
import 'package:audioplayers/audioplayers.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_icons/flutter_icons.dart';


class Music extends StatefulWidget {
var image;
var title;
var songurl;



  @override
  _MusicState createState() => _MusicState();

  Music(this.image, this.title, this.songurl);
}

class _MusicState extends State<Music> {
  bool playing = false; // at the begining we are not playing any song
  IconData playBtn = Icons.play_arrow; // the main state of the play button icon

  //Now let's start by creating our music player
  //first let's declare some object
  AudioPlayer _player;


  Duration position = new Duration();
  Duration musicLength = new Duration();

  Widget slider() {
    return Container(
      width: 300.0,
      child: Slider.adaptive(
          activeColor: Colors.amber[800],
          inactiveColor: Colors.grey[350],
          value: position.inSeconds.toDouble(),
          min: 0.0,
          max: musicLength.inSeconds.toDouble(),
          onChanged: (value) {
            seekToSec(value.toInt());
          }),
    );
  }

  //let's create the seek function that will allow us to go to a certain position of the music
  void seekToSec(int sec) {
    Duration newPos = Duration(seconds: sec);
    _player.seek(newPos);
  }


  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();

    _player = AudioPlayer();


    //now let's handle the audioplayer time

    //this function will allow you to get the music duration
    _player.durationHandler = (d) {
      setState(() {
        musicLength = d;
      });
    };

    //this function will allow us to move the cursor of the slider while we are playing the song
    _player.positionHandler = (p) {
      setState(() {
        position = p;
      });
    };

  }







  @override
  void dispose() {
    // TODO: implement dispose
    super.dispose();
_player.stop();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(

      appBar: getAppBar(),
      body: getBody(),
    );
  }

  Widget getAppBar() {
    return AppBar(
      centerTitle: true,
      title:Image.asset(
        'assets/images/logo.png',
        height:100,

      ),
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,


    );
  }

  Widget getBody() {
    var size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Stack(
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 30, right: 30, top: 20),
                child: Container(
                  width: size.width - 100,
                  height: size.width - 100,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(boxShadow: [
                    BoxShadow(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        blurRadius: 50,
                        spreadRadius: 5,
                        offset: Offset(-10, 40))
                  ], borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 30, right: 30, top: 20),
                child: Container(
                  width: size.width - 100,
                  height: size.width - 100,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      image: DecorationImage(
                          image: NetworkImage(widget.image), fit: BoxFit.cover),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 20,
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, right: 10),
            child: Container(
              width: size.width - 80,
              height: 70,
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [

                  Column(


                    children: [
                      Text(
                      widget.title,
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 18,
                            color: Colors.black,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      ),
                      Container(
                        width: 150,

                      )
                    ],
                  ),

                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 10,
          ),
         slider(),
          SizedBox(
            height: 20,
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 30, right: 30),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                Text(
                  "${position.inMinutes}:${position.inSeconds.remainder(60)}",
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.5)),
                ),
                Text(
                  "${musicLength.inMinutes}:${musicLength.inSeconds.remainder(60)}",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 18.0,
                  ),
                ),

              ],
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 25,
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(
                      Feather.shuffle,
                      color: Colors.amber[800].withOpacity(0.8),
                      size: 25,
                    ),
                    onPressed: null),
                IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(
                      Feather.skip_back,
                      color: Colors.amber[800].withOpacity(0.8),
                      size: 25,
                    ),
                    onPressed: null),
                IconButton(
                  iconSize: 62.0,
                  color: Colors.amber[800],
                  onPressed: () {
                    //here we will add the functionality of the play button
                    if (!playing) {
                      //now let's play the song
                      _player.play('https://livinghopemobile.com/public/storage/podcasts_audios/110621_051813_sound.mp3');
                      setState(() {
                        playBtn = Icons.pause;
                        playing = true;
                      });
                    } else {
                      _player.pause();
                      setState(() {
                        playBtn = Icons.play_arrow;
                        playing = false;
                      });
                    }
                  },
                  icon: Icon(
                    playBtn,
                  ),
                ),
                IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(
                      Feather.skip_forward,
                      color: Colors.amber[800].withOpacity(0.8),
                      size: 25,
                    ),
                    onPressed: null),
                IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(
                      AntDesign.retweet,
                      color: Colors.amber[800].withOpacity(0.8),
                      size: 25,
                    ),
                    onPressed: null)
              ],
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 25,
          ),

        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}


Performing hot restart...
Syncing files to device RMX2020...
Restarted application in 3,556ms.
I/GED     (19711): ged_boost_gpu_freq, level 100, eOrigin 2, final_idx 24, oppidx_max 24, oppidx_min 0
I/flutter (19711): The link codehttps://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ForBiggerBlazes.mp4
I/flutter (19711): {"status":200,"message":"Data fetched successfully","data":[{"id":8,"public_id":"832885b7-5fa5-48de-982e-9ef56b15ad3c","order_id":"1","title":".","image":"https:\/\/livinghopemobile.com\/public\/storage\/slider\/280421_173005_image.png","created_at":"2021-04-28T12:30:05.000000Z","updated_at":"2021-04-28T12:30:05.000000Z"},{"id":9,"public_id":"32638568-558b-4c56-91a6-ac43f0305104","order_id":"2","title":".","image":"https:\/\/livinghopemobile.com\/public\/storage\/slider\/280421_173028_image.png","created_at":"2021-04-28T12:30:28.000000Z","updated_at":"2021-04-28T12:30:28.000000Z"},{"id":10,"public_id":"c71aff90-34ed-4412-ac2c-659f67f62126","order_id":"3","title":".","image":"https:\/\/livinghopemobile.com\/public\/storage\/slider\/280421_173043_image.png","created_at":"2021-04-28T12:30:43.000000Z","updated_at":"2021-04-28T12:30:43.000000Z"},{"id":11,"public_id":"3eff3379-472c-4ae9-b707-53868449c775","order_id":"4","title":".","image":"https:\/\/livinghopemobile.com\/public\/storage\/slider\/280421_173057_ima
D/ColorViewRootUtil(19711): nav bar mode ignore false downX 47 downY 135 mScreenHeight 1600 mScreenWidth 720 mStatusBarHeight 36 globalScale 1.125 nav mode 0 rotation 0 event MotionEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, actionButton=0, id[0]=0, x[0]=47.933426, y[0]=135.91505, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, classification=NONE, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=133602519, downTime=133602519, deviceId=3, source=0x1002, displayId=0 }
D/ColorViewRootUtil(19711): nav bar mode ignore false downX 398 downY 469 mScreenHeight 1600 mScreenWidth 720 mStatusBarHeight 36 globalScale 1.125 nav mode 0 rotation 0 event MotionEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, actionButton=0, id[0]=0, x[0]=398.44662, y[0]=469.70645, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, classification=NONE, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=133603775, downTime=133603775, deviceId=3, source=0x1002, displayId=0 }
D/ColorViewRootUtil(19711): nav bar mode ignore false downX 259 downY 316 mScreenHeight 1600 mScreenWidth 720 mStatusBarHeight 36 globalScale 1.125 nav mode 0 rotation 0 event MotionEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, actionButton=0, id[0]=0, x[0]=259.6394, y[0]=316.802, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, classification=NONE, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=133606137, downTime=133606137, deviceId=3, source=0x1002, displayId=0 }
D/ColorViewRootUtil(19711): nav bar mode ignore false downX 366 downY 624 mScreenHeight 1600 mScreenWidth 720 mStatusBarHeight 36 globalScale 1.125 nav mode 0 rotation 0 event MotionEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, actionButton=0, id[0]=0, x[0]=366.491, y[0]=624.6096, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, classification=NONE, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=133608482, downTime=133608482, deviceId=3, source=0x1002, displayId=0 }
D/ColorViewRootUtil(19711): nav bar mode ignore false downX 252 downY 315 mScreenHeight 1600 mScreenWidth 720 mStatusBarHeight 36 globalScale 1.125 nav mode 0 rotation 0 event MotionEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, actionButton=0, id[0]=0, x[0]=252.64911, y[0]=315.8026, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, classification=NONE, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=133610727, downTime=133610727, deviceId=3, source=0x1002, displayId=0 }
D/ColorViewRootUtil(19711): nav bar mode ignore false downX 393 downY 1218 mScreenHeight 1600 mScreenWidth 720 mStatusBarHeight 36 globalScale 1.125 nav mode 0 rotation 0 event MotionEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, actionButton=0, id[0]=0, x[0]=393.45355, y[0]=1218.2386, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, classification=NONE, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=133611900, downTime=133611900, deviceId=3, source=0x1002, displayId=0 }
V/OppoMediaPlayer(19711): new OppoMediaPlayer
I/OppoMediaPlayer(19711): new mediaplayer ,packageName = living.hope.flutter_app
I/OppoMediaPlayer(19711): isPlaying() isOppoCreate=false
I/OppoMediaPlayer(19711): setAudioAttributes() isOppoCreate = false
I/OppoMediaPlayer(19711): setDataSource(String) isOppoCreate=false
I/OppoMediaPlayer(19711): setDataSource(path, headers) isOppoCreate=false
V/MediaHTTPService(19711): MediaHTTPService(android.media.MediaHTTPService@1ea502e): Cookies: null
I/OppoMediaPlayer(19711): prepareAsync() isOppoCreate=false
V/MediaHTTPService(19711): makeHTTPConnection: CookieHandler (java.net.CookieManager@d9ef650) exists.
V/MediaHTTPService(19711): makeHTTPConnection(android.media.MediaHTTPService@1ea502e): cookieHandler: java.net.CookieManager@d9ef650 Cookies: null
I/System.out(19711): [okhttp]:check permission begin!
W/System  (19711): ClassLoader referenced unknown path: system/framework/mediatek-cta.jar
I/System.out(19711): [okhttp] e:java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mediatek.cta.CtaUtils
I/System.out(19711): [socket]:check permission begin!
W/System  (19711): ClassLoader referenced unknown path: system/framework/mediatek-cta.jar
I/System.out(19711): [socket] e:java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mediatek.cta.CtaUtils
I/System.out(19711): [OkHttp] sendRequest>>
I/System.out(19711): [OkHttp] sendRequest<<
I/OppoMediaPlayer(19711): getMediaTimeProvider() isOppoCreate = false
D/MediaPlayer(19711): start()
I/OppoMediaPlayer(19711): start() isOppoCreate = false mCurrentState = 4
V/MediaRouter(19711): Selecting route: RouteInfo{ name=Phone, description=null, status=null, category=RouteCategory{ name=System types=ROUTE_TYPE_LIVE_AUDIO ROUTE_TYPE_LIVE_VIDEO  groupable=false }, supportedTypes=ROUTE_TYPE_LIVE_AUDIO ROUTE_TYPE_LIVE_VIDEO , presentationDisplay=null }
I/OppoMediaPlayer(19711): isPlaying() isOppoCreate=false

════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown building Music(dirty, dependencies: [MediaQuery], state: _MusicState#31ee3):
'package:flutter/src/material/slider.dart': Failed assertion: line 202 pos 15: 'value >= min && value <= max': is not true.

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  Music file:///Users/apple/livinghopev4/livinghope4android/lib/podcastegories/podcastwo.dart:111:66
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#2      new Slider.adaptive (package:flutter/src/material/slider.dart:202:15)
#3      _MusicState.slider (package:flutter_app/ui/Music.dart:37:21)
#4      _MusicState.getBody (package:flutter_app/ui/Music.dart:189:10)
#5      _MusicState.build (package:flutter_app/ui/Music.dart:100:13)
#6      StatefulElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4612:27)
...
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════
'package:flutter/src/material/slider.dart': Failed assertion: line 202 pos 15: 'value >= min && value <= max': is not true.
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  Music file:///Users/apple/livinghopev4/livinghope4android/lib/podcastegories/podcastwo.dart:111:66
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown building Music(dirty, dependencies: [MediaQuery], state: _MusicState#31ee3):
'package:flutter/src/material/slider.dart': Failed assertion: line 202 pos 15: 'value >= min && value <= max': is not true.

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  Music file:///Users/apple/livinghopev4/livinghope4android/lib/podcastegories/podcastwo.dart:111:66
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#2      new Slider.adaptive (package:flutter/src/material/slider.dart:202:15)
#3      _MusicState.slider (package:flutter_app/ui/Music.dart:37:21)
#4      _MusicState.getBody (package:flutter_app/ui/Music.dart:189:10)
#5      _MusicState.build (package:flutter_app/ui/Music.dart:100:13)
#6      StatefulElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4612:27)
...
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown building Music(dirty, dependencies: [MediaQuery], state: _MusicState#31ee3):
'package:flutter/src/material/slider.dart': Failed assertion: line 202 pos 15: 'value >= min && value <= max': is not true.

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  Music file:///Users/apple/livinghopev4/livinghope4android/lib/podcastegories/podcastwo.dart:111:66
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#2      new Slider.adaptive (package:flutter/src/material/slider.dart:202:15)
#3      _MusicState.slider (package:flutter_app/ui/Music.dart:37:21)
#4      _MusicState.getBody (package:flutter_app/ui/Music.dart:189:10)
#5      _MusicState.build (package:flutter_app/ui/Music.dart:100:13)
#6      StatefulElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4612:27)
...
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

Comment: What's the line 37 ? That's where it might be an error using the lib.

Comment: Certify that `position.inSeconds.toDouble()` is **always** `>= min` and `<= max`

Comment: @Linesofcode so how I can resolve it please let me know

Comment: @– BabC issue was in widget slider using progress bar please check

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 max: musicLength.inSeconds.toDouble()+1.0,
```

Just add this line and check. Hopes so it will solve your problem.

Comment: I have tried this already problem is that in some url it working but in some mp3 file it give same error I don't why?

Answer (score 0):

Simple Solution:
*Try to reset the slider value after the song has completed playing.
**Visit https://github.com/samupra/local_flutter_audio_player to learn more.

Comment: Need to more information to clearly understand the answer

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31398124)